# Replacing embedded TM symbol with PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have some code I am tidying up from our website, and in some places the web people have just copied text including the TM symbol, directly embedded (ie: NOT and HTML entity) like this:

```
<a href="#>SomeBrand™ product</a>
```

How can I replace this with PHP?  Or can I even?  I've tried:

```
$new_text = str_replace("™", "&trade;",$new_text);
$new_text = str_replace("&#8482;", "&trade;",$new_text);
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: What was the result of your attempts?  What is the value of $new_text?

Comment: @Devon the text is unaltered using the code above

Answer (score 2):

Try this one?

```
str_replace("\XE2\X84\XA2", "&trade;", $new_text);
```

Answer (score 1):

i think its mb

```
$new_text = 'Hello™ World!';
$new_text = mb_ereg_replace("™", "&trade",$new_text);
echo $new_text ;
```

output Hello&trade World!
// update

for php < 5.6.0

```
    mb_regex_encoding("UTF-8");
    $new_text = 'Hello™ World!';
    $new_text = mb_ereg_replace("™", "&trade",$new_text);
    echo $new_text ;
```

output Hello&trade World!
php 5.2.17
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/02f65a1065f1ec39515c69c3cb8528b3a298c055

Comment: Hmm, doesnt work for me - there could be something else I am missing - will keep trying

Comment: here code online , click execute code  ! and see result 
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3a474270cb2069c8035d1d4b4e0e39f5d748dd24

Comment: i mention if php version less than 5.6.0 it doesn't work
so please provide us you php version <?php phpinfo() ?>
or from console php -v

Comment: test on php 5.2.17 
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/02f65a1065f1ec39515c69c3cb8528b3a298c055

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "A 'trademark' is &trade;";

// Outputs: A 'trademark' is
echo html_entity_decode($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if you have a variable naming issue (since the input string is not altered.  Are you using the same variable name throughout? ...because look, `str_replace()` works:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/eGvLo))

```
$html = '<a href="#>SomeBrand™ product</a>';
$html = str_replace("™", "&trade;", $html);
echo $html;
```

Output:

```
<a href="#>SomeBrand&trade; product</a>
```